# Any way to get the width of a Context Menu before it is displayed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenustrip

I want to know the what the width of the context menu will be, just before being displayed, possibly in the `myContextMenu.popup` event handler or better yet, before `myContextMenu.show()`.

The reason I want to know the width, is so that I can affect the location of where it will be painted. Specifically, in the circumstance where the data of a column is right justified, when the operator right clicks, I don't want the context menu to cover the data, which is typically, also to the right. If I have the width, I can move the context menu to the left by the amount of the width and the top-right corner of the context menu will be at the point of the cursor.

I really do not want to use the `myContextMenu.DrawItem` event to paint the context menu items unless that is absolutely the only way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ContextMenuStrip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) has `Left`, `Top`, `Width` and `Height` properties which you can use to find its location and size.

Also to change the location, you can use [`SetBounds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad5ah3k5(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

The suitable event to correct the location is [`Opened`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opened(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

**Example**

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contextMenuStrip1.SetBounds(contextMenuStrip1.Left - contextMenuStrip1.Width,
        contextMenuStrip1.Top, 0, 0, BoundsSpecified.Location);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It is no wonder I could not get anywhere with what I was doing...I have been handling the mouse click events on my form and simply building a `ContextMenu` with `MenuItems`, which did not give me any access to what you have shown. Now I have to learn how to build a `ContextMenuStrip'. Fun! Thanks again!

Comment: You can create the ContextMenuStrip simply by dropping it on your form from toolbox. Then to show it, you can use code or simply assign it to `ContextMenuStrip` of the control (then by right clicking on that control, it will be shown automatically).

Comment: Neat, I'll try that. I'm trying to do most of my work in code, but I have a little sample project using the visual designer so that I can test out stuff like this and see how it works under the sheets. Thanks for the tip!!